# Как реализовать авторизацию в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, auth

Как создать форму для входа в андроид приложении и была возможность "запомнить" пользователя?

Я не могу понял сам алгоритм авторизации: у меня на данный момент есть сайт на котором пользователи уже зарегистрированы и мне теперь нужно перенести их на мобильное приложение, то есть что-бы они смогли используя свою учетную запись, пройти авторизацию в моём приложении и получить доступ к информации которая доступна и на сайте.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы.

Comment: Алгоритм точно такой же как и на сайте - поля для ввода, отправляем данные на сервер, получаем данные с сервера.

Comment: Какая часть не получается? Вёрстка? Сетевые запросы? Обработка ответа от сервера?

Comment: изначально я хочу понять с чего начинать, просто у меня есть на данный момент база пользователей которые есть на сайте, и мне нужно не создавая новую бд давать людям возможность заходить в приложение, ну и по этапам создания тоже пока-что не могу понять что за чем идет. Просто я на сайт регистрацию не создавал, мне сказали что нужно сделать приложение и все

Comment: Ну Вы приоткройте нам завесу тайны, как вообще приложение будет взаимодействовать с сайтом: API, парсинг страниц или отображение в `WebView`.

Comment: ну тайны пока нету, потому-что я сам толком не могу понять пока что делать, все те термины которые вы привели я не знаю, как api или webview  работают я не знаю

Comment: [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) - встраиваемый в приложение браузер. API - интерфейс реализованный на сервере, по которому клиент, отправляя определённые запросы, получает нужные данные в виде JSON, XML и тп

Comment: ну я думаю что будет реализован api, я думаю что все будет работать по принципу - на сервер поступает запрос и приложение получает ответ, при этом ответ показывается в адекватном виде в списке например

Comment: Для запоминания авторизованного пользователя посмотрите SharedPreferences